# Page Specific Styles via Sass / Compass

Tags: stylesheet, sass, compass-sass, code-organization

I want to use page specific styles such as contact.css (compiled) applied *only* to i.e. Contacts page.

I have a screen.css compiled which imports the _base.css that contains global variables, custom mixins, classes, etc., but the trouble is that I cannot use contact.css style if it contains global variables from _base.css — even with the screen.css set before contact.css (link) it always outputs error. And if I import the variables into the contact.scss itself I then get duplicate styles.

What should I do, how can I target a specific page and retain global variables in Sass?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create `_globalvariables.scss` and import that where you need it, including `_base.scss`.

For your `screen.scss` (or whatever), import `_base.scss`, for sheets such as `contact.scss` that only need the variables, only import in `_globalvariables.scss`.

In other words, keep your mixins and variables in a sheet without anything that will be compiled to CSS directly, so you can import it where you want without having to deal with duplicate style declarations.

Comment: screen.css in my case is a stylesheet for all pages, i.e. header, footer, etc. stylesheet.

It has base.css in it, and i.e. typography.css.If I put partials in contacts.css (variables, fonts, etc.) I mess up the cascade (easily seen with fonts). And if I put the contacts as a partial in screen.css everything works but then I don't have a page specific style, it is applied to all pages.

Simply, when I'm on a Contacts page how do I “insert”/“trigger” additional styling for that page, I still don't get it? :(

Perhaps you have any real world example of organization?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, update it with more information, re-word it, or provide some simple examples.